# executing SPeL on the applicationContext

Tags: spring, spring-el

I am trying to use SPeL to extract some data from the application context using

```
@Value
```

Precisely, I want this code as a value

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;

Map<String, CrudRepository> repos = 
context.getBeansOfType(CrudRepository.class);

@Value("#{...})
private Map<String, CrudRepository> repos;
```

is there a magic variable like "systemProperties" that I can invoke? There has to be!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
@Value("#{beanFactory.getBeansOfType(T(org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository))}")
private Map<String, MessageChannel> repos;
```

The SpEL here is based on the `BeanExpressionContext`, so its `getBeanFactory()` does the trick for us!

From other side you don't need `@Value` for the `Map<String, CrudRepository>`. The normal `@Autowired` works the same way.

Comment: You mean I can just autowire what I want? Let me give this a try

Comment: WOW DUDE! You can autowire! I had no idea! Can I give you like, 2 votes? 1 for answering the question and another for showing me why it's entirely not necessary?

Comment: :-). Well, you can vote to many other my answers. And yes: I'm glad that was helful.

Comment: Done! Since you're directly involved with spring it might be nice to have something like 'applicationContext' as a magic name. Since contexts can be named and there can be many, then you can refer to them by their names. Just a thought